# bazel - bazel rule in LLVM build file does not execute in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am working on integrating Polly into the LLVM build in TensorFlow. The bazel build in TensorFlow uses CMake to generate some of the header files. Reference -
[LLVM Build file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/third_party/llvm/llvm.BUILD)

However, I want to hand roll the bazel build files for Polly without using CMake.  `Opt` and `Polly` need to be added to the build dependencies. I have added a dummy rule to this file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "opt",
    srcs = glob([
        "tools/opt/*.c",
        "tools/opt/*.cpp",
        "tools/opt/*.h",
    ]),     
    hdrs = glob([
        "tools/opt/*.h",
    ]),     
    copts = ["-Iexternal/llvm/tools/opt","-Iexternal/llvm/include"],
    deps = [
        ":intrinsics_gen",
    ],
)
```

But this does not seem to work. I don't understand where I need to add the dependence to this rule, so it will be included in the build toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Nit: You can remove *.h from srcs. That will not help your issue though. What's the error message? What did you want to achieve with `copts` attribute? [includes](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.includes) is maybe helpful here, and I would also add a dependency (`deps` attribtue) to `llvm` target (the one that provides llvm/include/*.h). If `llvm` is a external repository, use `@llvm_repo//llvm_package:llvm_target` syntax.

Was this helpful?

Comment: Hi, I solved the error by defining a dependency in @tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/BUILD for @llvm:opt. It worked after that.